# HTML text still affect layout when it's already overflow from its parent

Tags: html, css, layout

For convenience, I set overflow as `visible`. The result is the same when overflow is `hidden` or `clip`. And div with border `dotted` is the text parent element. How do I fix it.

[When parent is full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk0zO.png)

[When parent is zero height, but the text will block parent move up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5j7p.png)

[Text still affect layout when it's already overflow from its parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhS4v.png)

[When remove text, layout return normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmGQv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I find out the problem that was caused by inline type display of parent. Inline display parent's child still affect layout even it is overflow from its parent. Changing parent's css display to block type can fix the problem.